# Show that the following limit is infinity

Tags: limits

I want to show that the limit of $$\frac{1}{n^\alpha \cdot \ln(n)}$$ is infinity where $\alpha < 0$. Is there an elementary way to show this? I know that $n^\alpha$ gets small faster then $\ln(n)$ gets large but still I can't find a formal proof. Thanks!

Edit: I look for a solution that uses only sequences rules and theorems, since I did not learn about functions yet.

Comment: You are looking for a solution only by sequence? You should add that to your question in order to make it clear.

Comment: @gimusi Okay. sorry. I edited the post.

Comment: What properties of the $\log$ function do you know, yet?

Answer (score 2):

A classic proof in high school that $\;\lim\dfrac{\log x}x=0$ consists in observing that, since $t\ge\sqrt t$ for $t\ge 1$, we have
$$\log x=\int_1^x\frac{\mathrm dt}t\le \int_1^x\frac{\mathrm dt}{\sqrt t}=2\bigl(\sqrt x-1\bigr)<2\sqrt x,$$ 
hence $\;\dfrac{\log x}x<\dfrac{2\sqrt x}x=\dfrac 2{\sqrt x}$, which tends to $0$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$.

Now , setting $\alpha =-a\;(a>0)$, we deduce that
$$\frac{1}{n^\alpha \cdot \log(n)}=\frac{n^a}{\log n}=a\frac{n^a}{\log(n^a)}\longrightarrow a\cdot +\infty=+\infty$$
by the above result.

Comment: "I look for a solution that uses only sequences rules and theorems, since I did not learn about functions yet"

Comment: How does the O.P. know about the log, then?

Comment: @gimusi: I don't see whay, in your 2nd displayed equation, the limit is $e^b$. Where has $a$ gone?

Comment: It seems you miscalculated $\;\sqrt[n]{e^{n^a}}$: it is equal to $\;e^{n^{a-1}}$.

Comment: What about the new version in your opinion?

Comment: Fine! There's  a typo in the last equation of the preliminary result:: it should start with $\;\frac n\log n} >a$.

Comment: Opssss... thanks a lot for your review!

Answer (score 1):

Attempt:

$a>0$.

$\dfrac{n^a}{\log n}= \dfrac{\exp(\log n^a)}{\log n}=$

$\dfrac{\exp (a\log n)}{\log n}.$

$z:= \log n.$

Now consider $z \rightarrow \infty$.

$f(z)=\dfrac{\exp (az)}{z} \gt (a^2/2!)z.$

Hence $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} f(z)=\infty.$

Used:

$e^x =1+x +x^2/2!...> x^2/2!$, $x >0$.

Comment: That seems nice even if the OP is looking "for a solution that uses only sequences rules and theorems, since I did not learn about functions yet"

Comment: Gimusi.True.Delete?Your thoughts?

Comment: My opinion is that you can let it of course. There are also other answers with more advanced approach than what requested by the asker, and your one is different. Moreover some other reader could be interested to it.

Answer (score 0):

With
$$\ln n<n-1$$
then
$$\dfrac{1}{n^a\ln n}>\dfrac{1}{n-1}n^{-a}\to\infty$$
for $-a>1$.

> **Edit:**
>   Might be helpful:
>   $$\ln x=\int_1^x\frac{\mathrm dt}t\le \int_1^x\frac{t^b\mathrm dt}{t}=\int_1^x t^{b-1}\mathrm dt=\frac{x^b-1}{b}<\frac{x^b}{b}$$
>   for real $b>0$. Now let $b=\dfrac{a}{2}$, then
>   $$\dfrac{1}{n^a\ln n}>\dfrac{1}{n^\frac{a}{2}n^\frac{a}{2}}\to\infty$$
>   if $-a>0$.

Comment: You don't have the case  $--1\le a<0$.

Comment: the rest is proved with integrals and isn't elementary.

Comment: For me it's elementary inasmuch as it only uses elementary properties of integrals, as seen in high school. Or the O.P. should give us the definition of the log he/she uses.

Comment: Sorry fro the (maybe stupid) question, but the first inequality is assumed as a given?

Comment: As you know that one is proven with calculus, Isn't that?